# GraphQL association issue

Tags: graphql, lodash, express-graphql

Before diving into the code, here is a high-level explanation of my question:

In my `GraphQL` schema, I have two root types: **Developers** and **Projects**. I'm attempting to find all developers who are part of a given project. The query might look like this:

```
{
  project(id:2) {
    title
    developers {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I'm getting a `null` value for **developers**.

**Dummy data**

```
const developers = [
  {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Brent',
    lastName: 'Journeyman',
    projectIds: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    firstName: 'Laura',
    lastName: 'Peterson',
    projectIds: ['2']
  }
]

const projects = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Experimental Drug Bonanza',
    company: 'Pfizer',
    duration: 20,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Terrible Coffee Holiday Sale',
    company: 'Starbucks',
    duration: 45,
  }
]
```

So, Brent has worked on both projects. Laura has worked on the second project. My issue is in the `resolve` function in `ProjectType`. I've tried many queries, but none seem to work.

**ProjectType**

```
const ProjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Project',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    company: { type: GraphQLString },
    duration: { type: GraphQLInt },
    developers: {
      type: GraphQLList(DeveloperType),

      resolve(parent, args) {           
        ///////////////////////
        // HERE IS THE ISSUE //
        //////////////////////
        return _.find(developers, { id: ? });
      }

    }
  })
})
```

**DeveloperType**

```
const DeveloperType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Developer',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
    lastName: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to return all the developers having current project's `id` in their `.projectIds`, right?

First, `_.find` cannot help since it returns first matched element and you need to get array with developers(since field has `GraphQLList` type).

So how about

```
resolve(parent, args) {
    return developers.filter(
        ({projectIds}) => projectIds.indexOf(parent.id) !== -1
    );
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. I'd gotten very close with filter, but now see where I went wrong. Thank you!